# How to clear an input element when clicking on a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search filter input which works:

```
<form id="filter-form" action="">
      <p>Search table: <input name="filter"  id="filter" value="" maxlength="30" size="30" type="text"></p>
</form>
```

From a sidebar I have, I'm clicking on a link to change the tables to either all or test.
When I click on it, it does change the tables and it is clearing up the input but 
when 'test' table appears the filter(text) from last time I enter is still applicable.

How would I get it to clear the filter and not have last time enter text?

```
<ul>
<li><a id="all" href="#1"   onclick="changeClass('all')">All</a></li>
<li><a id="test" href="#2"  onclick="changeClass('test');" >2</a></li>

</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeClass(x){
        if(x=="all"){           
            $("#t01").hide();
            $("#t02").show();

document.getElementById("filter").value="";         
        }
        else if(x == "corporate"){          
            $("#t01").show();
            $("#t02").hide();
            document.getElementById("filter").value="";

    }
</script>
```

Comment: The code you have should clear it... Is there an error message in the console?

Answer (score 3):

If I'm getting the question right, you could use a click handler:

```
$("#all, #test").on('click', function() {
  $("#filter").val('');
});
```

Edit: [Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yc03y0cm/14/) that might help out.  There's two click handlers in here, one for each `<a>` element clicked.

Comment: with this i get error,Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: @jfishbow I added a JSFiddle - let me know if this helps you out.

Comment: Your answer is missing a closing parenthesis, but your fiddle looks good.

Comment: since im getting error 'TypeError: $(...).on is not a function'
it probably means it has to do with the script since i have 
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js, correct?

Comment: I'd have to see the actual lines you're getting the error at.  Your version of jQuery *is* a little outdated, though.

Comment: it would be this line $("#all").on('click', function() {

Comment: `.on()` was added in jQuery 1.7, but you're using 1.5.1, which doesn't have it. You could upgrade to the latest version, or alternatively, the [jQuery click function](http://api.jquery.com/click/) will work similarly.  Please mark my answer as a solution if this helps to solve your problem!

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this helps. Simplified your function a little using [`jQuery.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) and cleared the input field using `.val('')`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="filter-form" action="">
      <p>Search table: <input name="filter" id="filter" value="" maxlength="30" size="30" type="text"></p>
</form>
    
<ul>
    <li><a id="all" href="#1"   onclick="changeClass('all')">All</a></li>
    <li><a id="test" href="#2"  onclick="changeClass('test');">2</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
    function changeClass(x){
        $('#t01').toggle(x != 'all');
        $('#t02').toggle(x == 'all');
        $('#filter').val('');
    }
</script>
```

Alex is doing it the best way though, using jQuery to attach click handlers instead of inline.